# Rails 4 controller actions duplicated JSON responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I use a lot of AJAX POST requests to my controllers (in Rails 4). There is duplication in response part of virtually every action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  def remove_avatar
    user = current_user
    user.avatar = nil

    if user.save
      render json: { success: true }
    else
      render json: { success: false }
    end
  end

  def make_admin
    user = current_user
    user.admin = true

    if user.save
      render json: { success: true }
    else
      render json: { success: false }
    end
  end

  # lot of other similar actions

end
```

The repeating part is json rendered with boolean value which depends on whether model instance is saved successfully. In JavaScript files I handle the response and do different things according to received JSON response.

Can I simplify this code somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write render json once and in success response you have to just write @user.save which returns true or false

```
render json: {success: user.save}
```

Comment: If you're really trying to cut down on LOCs, then `render json: { success: current_user.update_attributes(admin: true) }`